# Is there a 10 player expansion for Settlers of Catan? Where can I get it?

Tags: catan

Somebody told me that he has an extension for Settlers of Catan that allows play with up to ten players. Who made it?

Is it still sold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [video of a 10 player game](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o78Xhjd7Lu8).

I don't believe there is anything official, but as the video demonstrates, its just a matter of putting together a couple extra sets to get a playable 10 player game.

I'd imagine the trading rounds would be a bit chaotic though!

Answer (score 7):

We have played an 8 player game.  We simply used two sets, making the board huge.  We played with the expansion rules (IE special building phases)

~~edit~~

For pieces, we already had the 6 player expansion.  For the additional 2 players, we used black and grey Lego pieces.

Answer (score 4):

I have used PhotoShop to make my own resource hexes, as well as new development cards.  We have never used all the things I have made, but if we did, it would be possible to have 15 players in a game.  I have a "gold" resource hex; a "development card" resource hex; a "pie" resource hex [(like Trivial Pursuit) (has all five normal resources plus a gold, for a total of 6)]; "gold" harbors (2 for 1, and 3 for 1); and even more!  I also have made, as stated, new development cards to speed up the game, and make it more interesting.  Currently there are 9 of them.  One of them is a "lottery winner" development card.  It allows you to pick up any 10 resource cards and 3 development cards.  Using all my variations, we have finished games in 20-25 minutes.  We have not used the original set-up for several years, as our family prefers to have things which make the game more interesting.  Guess you could say that we have outgrown the original version(s), due to an excessive amount of play.  Love this game!!

Comment: Did you ever play with 10 people using your homebrew materials?

Comment: What do you do with gold?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, you have to either nerf or totally remove the **Monopoly** card. A suggestion could be to allow it to steal only 1 resource from each player, but I feel it could be too powerful even in that case.

Since there would have to be a huge number of hexes, the luck would increase too much, hence I would recommend [a diceless variant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/549/alternative-for-dice-in-settlers-of-catan/1128#1128).

You should also allow at least two "longest road" and "most knights" bonuses.

Finally, you would really have to strictly limit the trade phase somehow.

Comment: You might limit the Monopoly card to 2 resources like the Resource Monopoly card from Cities and Knights. "Name a resource. Each player must give you 2 of that type of resource if they have them."

Comment: @Greg as I said, it could be too powerful even if you limited that to _one_ resource...

Comment: Sure, the players will have to agree to something they are comfortable with. I am just pointing out an option used by the Catan franchise.

Answer (score 2):

it shouldnt be difficult just add more extension packs (which add 2 players) and either paint them different colours or build new pieces. it is a good idea to have two longest road and largest army. however the monopoly card( or any other rules) shouldnt be needed to mess with, yes the monopoly is powerful but the 7 is rolled the most ( most likely anyway) and this would negate the monopoly card.